# What memcache client to use for JRuby and Rails 3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, memcached, jruby

I have used MRI Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3 with the memcached gem, and when experimenting with JRuby and Rails 2.3, I found the jruby-memcache-client gem had a good story and seemed to work well.

However, moving to JRuby 1.9 and Rails 3, is that still the proper gem to use? Or has the built-in memcache client gem been improved to the point where the threading issues that drove the development of jruby-memcache-client have been addressed? Or should I use Dalli?

Answer (score 0):

I use Dalli both with Rails 3.0.x and 1.8.7 production environment, and a Rails 3.1.x and 1.9.3 dev branch successfully. Works great in both environments.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Beyond it working - jruby-memcache-client's docs say:

"The Ruby MemCache library was never written with threaded applications in mind. All threads use the same socket, and multithreaded mode basically wraps the IO with a Mutex"

and discuss pooling. In other words, even the built-in client, would "work great" but would not perform as well under load in a multithreaded setting. I don't know if Dalli has the same limitations?

Did you compare Dalli to other options, or do any benchmarking? Or is it just that Dalli produced no errors?